# iOS enterprise distribution - how long is app valid?

Tags: ios

I do have an Enterprise Developer Account with a distribution certificate expiring on 2017-10-28.

The distribution provisioning profile is expiring by the end of this month, now I'm interested if I need to distribute a new version or if the currently distributed apps will continue to run after this month (as the certificate lasts longer).

For already installed apps, is the expiration date of the certificate important (which would mean I don't have to generate a new version until october 2017) or the provisioning profile's expiration date (which means I need to create and distribute a new version now)?

Answer (score 0):

If Profile expires you have to regenerate a new profile and build your app. Once profile is expired you will NOT be able to launch the app.

Comment: I guess you mean "will NOT be able to launch the app"? So this means that with enterprise distribution I have to make a new version every year?

Comment: Yes, Not be able to launch. Yeah you have a make new version every year

Answer (score 0):

If profile is expired and if you are about to run the app

```
      1.You can't run the app.Even if you try to run the app it shows alert error.
      2.It shows 'The profile has Expired' in Key Chain
      3.Again you need to create new distribution profile.
      4.Also you need to take new build for run the app.
```

Thank You